# How to find online players for San Juan?

Tags: online, san-juan

Where is a good place to ask for?

I googled a lot, also googled nicknames I see in San Juan leader board, but no success.

San Juan uses GameCenter in the iOS version, but Apple reduced a lot of functionality from GameCenter and Ravensburger didn‘t implement its own social game network, and it seems they dont do it in the future.

So it is almost impossible to find new player friends because friend requests are not working anymore, even you can send some.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the app you are using and you need to contact the developer to get help.

Comment: Yes, the game manufactor could change it maybe, but they dont do updates anymore. But still a lot of people play this game, I can see them in the leaderboard but I‘m unable to contact them. This people got there friend connections before Apple changed/reduced the GameCenter functionality. So it seems I have to find other players without GameCenter, like the answer on brettspielwelt says. I‘m already searching there ...

Comment: I am not sure what you expect anyone but the developer to do to help you fix the issue of being unable to contact or make connections with people on the leader board.

Comment: Maybe there are ways to contact Game Center members outside the game (it uses a REST web service). And the tip about other communities was great. The question is ‚How to find online players?‘, not contact them only in the app over Game Center. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Asking about contacting game center members outside of the game is not in the scope of this site and you might be able to get an answer on the apple stack exchange site.

Comment: Then delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider joining BrettSpielWelt.
http://brettspielwelt.de

You may still play on your iDevice, even though it will be through the browser and not the San Juan app.

The user interface takes some getting used to, but once you get through that, it's a good way to find opponents for quite a few boardgames.

As a distant plan B, you may download JSanJuan, and play against the computer.
http://www.compoundeye.net/jsanjuan/

Comment: While this does give options to play online I don't think it addresses the question which is related to playing on iOS and not a computer.